# Laravel/Eloquent whereIn/where with a pair of sets

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in my database.

The first two tables are just normal tables with an ID and some other columns like:

#### Table 1

| ID | col01 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |

#### Table 2

| ID | col01 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |

The third table is some kind of a relation/assignment table:

#### Table 3

| ID | table1_id | table2_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | .. |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | .. |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | .. |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | .. |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | .. |

Now I do have a SQL statement which does exactly what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM table_3 where (table1_id, table2_id) in ( (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3));
```

---

So Im sending following Request Body to the API:

```
   {
        "assignments": [
            {
                "table1_id": 1,
                "table2_id": 1
            },
            {
                "table1_id": 2,
                "table2_id": 1
            },
            {
                "table1_id": 3,
                "table2_id": 3
            }
        ]
    }
```

I do validate my the request with

```
->validate($request, 
[         
    'assignments' => 'required|array',
    'assignments.*.table1_id' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:20',
    'assignments.*.table2_id' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:20' 
]
```

Now Im kinda stuck how to use the eloquent commands (e.g. whereIn) to get my desired output.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

So I took the workaround of arcanedev-maroc mentioned here: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1021

and edited it to fit my Request.

Works like a charm.

Comment: You say you have a raw SQL query that works and in your final sentence you talk about eloquent. Do you need eloquent or can you build the raw query code wise?

Comment: Do you have models and relationships set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took the workaround of arcanedev-maroc mentioned here: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1021

and edited it to fit my Request.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not provide any functions by default. The core team said that they would not maintain this feature. You can read the post [here](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1021).

But you can create your own query to accomplish this. I am providing a function that you can use as per your specification:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $body=$request->input('data');
    $data=json_decode($body)->assignments;
    $query='(table1_id, table2_id) in (';
    $param=array();
    foreach($data as $datum)
    {
        $query=$query."(".$datum->table1_id.",".$datum->table2_id."), ";
    }
    $query = rtrim($query, ", ");
    $query = $query.")";
    $result=DB::table('table3')->whereRaw($query)->get();
    return $result;
}
```